# Java application output data are missing something

Tags: java, swing

Thank you some member help me to correct the code, but I have more questions to ask :

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Average2 {
public static void main(String args[]) {
int total;
int gradeCounter;
int grade = 0;
int result;
int passed = 0;
int failed = 0;
int absent = 0;

double average;

String gradeString;
String s1;

total = 0;
gradeCounter = 1;

gradeString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Exam Marks first or -1 to Quit:");
grade = Integer.parseInt(gradeString);

String output = "Name of the Student\tExam Marks\n";
String ns = "No. of student passed: \t No. of students failed: \t No. of student Absent: \n";

if (grade != -1) {
    s1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the Name of Student - ");
    output += gradeCounter + "\t" + s1 + "\t" + gradeString + "\n";
    ns = "no. of students passed:" + passed + "\n no. of students failed:" + failed + "\n no. of students absent:" + absent;

    while (grade != -1) {
      if(grade >= 40){
      passed = passed + 1;
            }
      else if(grade > 0 && grade < 40){
      failed = failed + 1;
            }
            else if(grade > 0 && grade <1){ //why grade can't check = 0??
                absent = absent + 1; //
            }

        total = total + grade;
        gradeCounter = gradeCounter + 1;

        gradeString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Exam Marks  or -1 to Quit:" + gradeCounter);
        grade = Integer.parseInt(gradeString);
        if (grade == -1) {
            break;
        }
        s1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the Name of Student - " + gradeString);
        output += gradeCounter + "\t" + s1 + "\t" + gradeString + "\n";
        ns = "no. of students passed:" + passed + "\n no. of students failed:" + failed + "\n no. of students absent:" + absent;
    }

}

DecimalFormat twoDigits = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

if (gradeCounter != 0) {

    average = (double) total / (gradeCounter-1);

    JTextArea outputArea = new JTextArea();
    outputArea.setText(output);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, outputArea,
    "Analysis of Exam Marks", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ns,
    "Analysis of Exam Marks", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Class average is " + twoDigits.format(average), "Class Average",
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

}

else
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No grades were entered", "Class Average",
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

System.exit(0);
}
}
```

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/sn8VJ.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQCuw.png)

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yG6g.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6VUY.png)

why if(grade = 0) will be error and the the result absent can't increase??

In this case, how to use the Math.squr to calculate standard deviation??

Comment: Why is javascript tagged here? Javascript != Java

Comment: Are you even storing the previously entered data anywhere? I dont know if I missed something, but I didnt see you having used any data structures to store data at runtime.

Comment: Let me know your inputs and expected output

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are reading the two inputs outside your `while` loop the first time and then replacing their values inside the `while` loop again.

```
gradeString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Integer Grade or -1 to Quit:" );
s1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "Enter the Name of Student - " );
grade = Integer.parseInt( gradeString );
```

You are appending these inputs to your `output` String only in the while loop and not outside.

You can do one of the following:

1. Append it to the `output` outside your `while` loop by doing:

   ```
   String output = "Name of the Student\tExam Marks\n";
   output += gradeCounter + "\t" + s1 + "\t" + gradeString + "\n";
   ```
2. Simple remove these statements as you are anyways calling them inside your `while` loop

Comment: @Hey_sT Just initialize the variable `grade` to 0 by doing `int grade = 0;`

Answer (score 0):

Made the changes in the following version of the code. It should work as you wanted.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Average {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int total;
    int gradeCounter;
    int grade;

    double average;

    String gradeString;
    String s1;

    total = 0;
    gradeCounter = 1;

    gradeString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Integer Grade or -1 to Quit:");
    grade = Integer.parseInt(gradeString);
    String output = "Name of the Student\tExam Marks\n";
    if (grade != -1) {
        s1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the Name of Student - ");
        output = gradeCounter + "\t" + s1 + "\t" + gradeString + "\n";

        while (grade != -1) {
            total = total + grade;
            gradeCounter = gradeCounter + 1;

            gradeString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Integer Grade or -1 to Quit:" + s1);
            grade = Integer.parseInt(gradeString);
            if (grade == -1) {
                break;
            }
            s1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the Name of Student - " + gradeCounter);
            output += gradeCounter + "\t" + s1 + "\t" + gradeString + "\n";
        }

    }

    DecimalFormat twoDigits = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

    if (gradeCounter != 0) {

        average = (double) total / gradeCounter;

        JTextArea outputArea = new JTextArea();
        outputArea.setText(output);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, outputArea, "Analysis of Exam Marks", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Class average is " + twoDigits.format(average), "Class Average",
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    }

    else
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No grades were entered", "Class Average",
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    System.exit(0);
}
}
```